# Apache Spark Dataframe - Load data from nth line of a CSV file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I would like to process a huge order CSV file (5GB), with some metadata rows at the start of file.
Header columns are represented in row 4 (starting with "h,") followed by another metadata row, describing optionality. Data rows start with "d,"

```
m,Version,v1.0
m,Type,xx
m,<OtherMetaData>,<...>
h,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,.............,Col100
m,Mandatory,Optional,Optional,...........,Mandatory
d,Val1,Val2,Val3,Val4,Val5,.............,Val100
```

Is it possible to skip a specified number of rows when loading the file and use 'inferSchema' option for DataSet?

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
            .format("csv")
            .option("header", "true")
            .option("inferSchema", "true")
            .load("\home\user\data\20170326.csv");
```

Or do I need to define two different Datasets and use "except(Dataset other)" to exclude the dataset with rows to be ignored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try setting the `"comment"` option to `"m"`, effectively telling the csv reader to skip lines beginning with the `"m"` character.

```
df = spark.read()
          .format("csv")
          .option("header", "true")
          .option("inferSchema", "true")
          .option("comment", "m")
          .load("\home\user\data\20170326.csv")
```