# Load a CSV file from line 17 of the file in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem with the dataframe of spark in scala. I'm using the method `var df = spark.read.format("csv").load("csvfile.csv")` to read a CSV file and store it in a DF. My CSV file has 16 lines of some comments that I don't want to read. I have not discover the way to say to avoid a header, but it is only of one line. Any idea?

Thanks you.

Comment: there is `comment` for spark csv load...

Comment: Are the comments delimited by anything?

Comment: I can't use the `coment` way because they must begin with '#' but in my case, I have lines which start with any character and I can't change that. The only way to know the limit of the comments is that they will take always 16 lines.

Comment: You can use comment option for any symbol. It will work for  number / special character / alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution1 work only for comments starting with only one common symbol/alphabets. solution2 work for all the symbols adding in the List in the solution.

Solution 1:

If all the comments are starting with common letter/symbol/number, give that symbol in the `option` value for key `comment` as in this answer.

[Apache Spark Dataframe - Load data from nth line of a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43029020/apache-spark-dataframe-load-data-from-nth-line-of-a-csv-file)

But if some comments are starting with different symbols from rest of comments, this won't work out.

Solution 2:

In this solution, I am removing the lines starting with symbols `*` , `/` and number `7`. Replace the `List` values based on the starting letters of your actual comments.

```
import ss.implicits._

val rd = ss.sparkContext.textFile(path)

rd.filter(x => !List('*','7','/').contains(x.charAt(0))) // reading file as RDD and filtering records starting with comment letters or symbols or alphabets
.map(x => x.split(","))
.map(x => (x(0),x(1),x(2),x(3)))
.toDF("id","name","department","amount")
.show()
```

Input :

```
*ghfghfgh
*mgffhfg
/fgfgdfgf
7gdfgh
1,Praveen,d1,30000
2,naveen,d1,40000
3,pavan,d1,50000
```

Output :

```
+---+-------+----------+------+
| id|   name|department|amount|
+---+-------+----------+------+
|  1|Praveen|        d1| 30000|
|  2| naveen|        d1| 40000|
|  3|  pavan|        d1| 50000|
+---+-------+----------+------+
```

In the above example first four lines in input are comments.